# How prevent duplicate items in javascript array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

i'm using data-table in react
i have a lot of row and one cell in this row editable. onBlur function i'm getting the changed value and push to some array with this way.

```
let editedData = []

 editedData.push({
   total: this.state.data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id],
   id: cellInfo.row._original.id,
   comment: cellInfo.row.comment
 });
```

there is unique id of each row. Everything work well but my records are repeating.

so is like:

```
0: {total: "40222", id: "c296b0f2-0ed9-49fa-bf33-e14151a197d5", comment: null}
1: {total: "40222222", id: "c296b0f2-0ed9-49fa-bf33-e14151a197d5", comment: null}
```

here is total property is coming from editable input. 
i want to make prevent duplicating record in my editedData array.

how realize this logic?

if this id already is have in my editedData array just change total property ?

Comment: How about having a global Set for all the ids? [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Using Set as @tomerpacific said is better for this case, but you can also store then in a object with that id as a key

Comment: no i just have a data which inside have these id's in my react component state

Comment: how using it in my case?.